# Google Dataflow workflow error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run a preprocessing task using Google Dataflow on Cloud-ML. I am getting the following error

Workflow failed. Causes: (c70954cc80d0504c): One or more access checks for temp location or staged files failed. Please refer to other error messages for details. For more information on security and permissions

Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Srini.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is your stagingLocation set to? What arguments is the job being run with?

Comment: Thanks for the response Idrees. So my staging location is set to the bucket location gs://<BucketName>. I am pasting the relevant job log from dataflow web interface, to get a deeper context of the exception I am getting:    (46c3b12a44f5a2db): Staged package cloudml-0.1.9-alpha.tar.gz at location 'gs://dataflow-sct-ml/flowers__20170223_170110/preproc/temp/flowers-20170223-170112.1487869273.754931/cloudml-0.1.9-alpha.tar.gz' is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to indicate that the bucket you're using isn't configured to be accessible from the project on which you are running the job.  It is suggested that you use a bucket owned by the same project on which you run the job.  For more guidance, see:

- https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets
- https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#security-and-permissions-for-pipelines-on-cloud-platform

Comment: Thanks for the response Charles. The bucket I am using is actually created within the same project. I also looked into permissions given to service accounts created for 'Cloud-ML' and 'Dataflow' which are the API's I enabled for my project. I have explicitly given 'Owner' permission to both of these accounts, which is the highest level permission, to see if they can access the bucket location. But none of these helped, please suggest if you see any other possible workaround I can try.

Comment: Can you check if your production system are using any specific network and subnetworks. If so your dataflow should also be present in same network e.g. "production" network. This is very useful if you are accessing any of dataflow services on private IPs as if so, then you need to be in same network as your resources are.